# Incremental number with specific format

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I need to make an id with a specific  format  where 2 first digit are year, and the rest are just incremental number with `000` as spacer between year and incremental number where the qty of `0` will decrease along with increasingly incremental number such as `190001`,`190002`,.....,`190180`,...,`191400`. 
All i can think of using

```
$id = '';
if(srtrlen($number) == 1){
   $id = date('y',time()).'000'.$number;
}
elseif(strlen($number)==2){
   $id = date('y',time()).'00'.$number;
}
.
.
.
else{
   $id = date('y',time()).$number;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use str_pad.

```
$id = '';
if(srtrlen($number) == 1){
    $id = date('y',time()).str_pad($number, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
elseif(strlen($number)==2){
   $id = date('y',time()).str_pad($number, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
.
.
.
else{
   $id = date('y',time()).$number;
}
```

Comment: You could always use `str_pad($number, 4-strlen($number), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)` to save the `if...`